# Irssi: /LASTLOG match -file /tmp/irssi_discussion

Tags: irc, irssi

I have tried to save the match "/lastlog match" to a file /tmp/irssi_discussion. I can get it work like "/lastlog /tmp/irssi_discussion" that saves the whole buffer, noted in the [documentation](http://irssi.org/documentation/startup#c7). However, it fails on its variant.

How can I get the command "/LASTLOG match -file /tmp/irssi_discussion" working in Irssi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the pattern to match after the file, so:

```
/LASTLOG -file /tmp/irssi_discussion match
```

To get the full help information do:

```
/HELP lastlog
```

That includes the specific syntax details:

```
LASTLOG [-] [-file <filename>] [-window <ref#|name>] [-new | -away] [-<level>-<level...>] [-clear] [-count] [-case] [-regexp | -word] [-before[<#>]] [-after [<#>]] [-<# before+after>] [<pattern>] [<count>[<start>]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought the "[-]"-sign meant a pattern, hence the confusion.

Comment: What does the [-]-sign actually mean?

Comment: -: don't print the "Lastlog:" and "End of Lastlog" messages.